# Analyzing squid3 access.log log files with a all-in-one shell script

Tags: logging, log-files, shell-scripting

I'm just going to write a shell script that me the essential functions such as SARG offers.

- Sort by URLs with most hits (Top100 in 10min out of 10k)
- Sum of status / error codes
- As well as sorting by URL's with Many bandwidth consumption
- and some more sort function

Unfortunately, I have a problem with the function of sorting by URL's with most Bandwith. Have there already with all sorts of attempts, but always the same problem: either not working, or are added together, the total bytes in the 2nd spallte ... Does anyone have any idea how I can implement the best?

raw accecc.log (common style)

```
 > tail /var/log/squid3/access.log
    192.168.1.208 - - [10/Jan/2016:19:01:44 -0100] "CONNECT i.ytimg.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 143903 TCP_MISS:HIER_DIRECT
    192.168.1.208 - - [10/Jan/2016:19:02:02 -0100] "CONNECT www.youtube.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 87392 TCP_MISS:HIER_DIRECT
    192.168.1.208 - - [10/Jan/2016:19:02:12 -0100] "CONNECT s.ytimg.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 32718 TCP_MISS:HIER_DIRECT
    192.168.1.208 - - [10/Jan/2016:19:03:00 -0100] "CONNECT s.youtube.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 6376 TCP_MISS:HIER_DIRECT
    192.168.1.208 - - [10/Jan/2016:19:03:39 -0100] "CONNECT r2---sn-h0j7snel.googlevideo.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 13740382 TCP_MISS:HIER_DIRECT
    192.168.1.208 - - [10/Jan/2016:19:03:40 -0100] "CONNECT r2---sn-h0j7snel.googlevideo.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 18250979 TCP_MISS:HIER_DIRECT
    192.168.1.208 - - [10/Jan/2016:19:06:57 -0100] "CONNECT token.services.mozilla.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 4138 TCP_MISS:HIER_DIRECT
    192.168.1.208 - - [10/Jan/2016:19:07:53 -0100] "CONNECT sync-285-us-west-2.sync.services.mozilla.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 4749 TCP_MISS:HIER_DIRECT
    192.168.1.208 - - [10/Jan/2016:19:41:48 -0100] "CONNECT sync-285-us-west-2.sync.services.mozilla.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 4118 TCP_MISS:HIER_DIRECT
    192.168.1.208 - - [10/Jan/2016:19:51:49 -0100] "CONNECT sync-285-us-west-2.sync.services.mozilla.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 4118 TCP_MISS:HIER_DIRECT
```

prozessed and saved in a temp file

cat /tmp/bandwith.tmp

```
anonymousstats.keefox.org 5128
anonymousstats.keefox.org 3438
api.accounts.firefox.com:443 5509
api.flattr.com:443 4418
api.flattr.com:443 10397
blocklist.addons.mozilla.org:443 24118
button.flattr.com 4180
clients1.google.com 861
clients1.google.com 861
clients1.google.com 861
clients1.google.com 861
clients1.google.com 861
clients1.google.com 861
clients1.google.com 861
clients1.google.com 861
clients1.google.com 861
cm.g.doubleclick.net 4437
content.googleapis.com:443 4317
content.googleapis.com:443 4914
```

wished form:

```
anonymousstats.keefox.org 8566
api.accounts.firefox.com:443 5509
api.flattr.com:443 14815
blocklist.addons.mozilla.org:443 24118
button.flattr.com:443 4180
clients1.google.com 7749
cm.g.doubleclick.net:443 4437
content.googleapis.com:443 8754
```

My Function at this point:

```
bandwith() {
#First Idee: awk '{print $10, $7}' "$LOGDATEI" | grep -vE "(^\"-\"$|/www.$HOST|/$HOST)" | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -$HITS > /tmp/bandwith.tmp
cat "$LOGDATEI" | awk '{print $10,  $7}' | awk '{ sub(/http\:\/\//, ""); sub(/\//, " " ); print $2, $1 } ' | sort -d | head -$HITS > /tmp/bandwith.tmp
```

I tried:

```
while read LINE
do
    cut -d' ' -f2 /tmp/bandwith.tmp { while read NR
do
x=$(($x+$NR))

echo $x
}
```

or

```
awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum}' foo.txt


rule1=`head -1 /tmp/bandwith.tmp | awk '{print $1}'`
rule2=`head -2 /tmp/bandwith.tmp | awk '{print $1}'`

for word in `cat /tmp/bandwith.tmp`       
cat /tmp/bandwith.tmp |  while read line 
 do 
    echo "Processing new line" >/dev/tty
    $sum = $zeile1 + $zeile2
done 

}    
     until [ "$rule1" != "$rule2" ]
     do      
       echo "$1"
       echo "$2"
     break
    echo "Only to test"
   done
done
}
```

someone an idee for this problem?